# Largest number k one-to-one function

Tags: functions

What is the largest number k for which there exist a one-to-one function f : {x ∈ Z : x < $k^3$} → {1,3,5,7,9,11}

So if k is an integer, and x is in Z, wouldn't there be an infinite amount of x < $k^3$ no matter what k is? And for it to be one to one I need 6 x, correct? Help me to see what I'm missing.

Comment: Is $x \in \Bbb Z$ or $\Bbb N$ ?

Comment: If it's $\mathbb Z$ then you're right, but then it's a trick question, which seems unlikely.

Comment: @ChinnapparajR Assuming x was in N, I'm still not sure how I'd get a one to one function. If k = 2 , then it's for Natural numbers less than 8 , which is (1....7) but we have only 6 elements in the co-domain. but I guess we could have k be a fraction?